# Issue with Indy FTP component

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

I am using Delphi 6 with Indy FTP component, having an issue with transferring files over 2GB. Small files are working fine.

Has anyone faced similar issues like that?

**UPDATE:**

There is one issue after upgrading from Indy 9 to Indy 10. This code no longer compiles:

```pascal
TbaseFTP = Class(idftp) 
Private 
  Jonwrite : TFTPDataLogEvent; 
  Jonread : TFTPDataLogEvent;

Public 
  Procedure WriteLn(Const POut : string = ''); Override; 
  Function ReadLn(PTerminate : string = LF; const Ptimeout : Integer = IdTimeoutDefault; PMaxllength : integer = -1):string ;override;

Implementation

Procedure TbaseFTP.writeLn(Const Pout : string = '');
Begin 
  if assigned (JOnWrite) then 
    JonWrite(Pout);
  inherited; 
End;
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it is very hard to suggest any changes. Please edit your question and provide a [mre]

Comment: Hi Tom, it looks more issue with support of above 2gb file. I have found on other forum that Indy Component has limitation of above 2 gb file just want to make sure it is correct or anyone face similar issue like that, because code is working with less then 2gb files. Thanks

Comment: Which version of Indy are you using? The one that shipped with Delphi 6, or a newer one? Delphi 6 was the first version to support 64bit streams, so TIdFTP should be able to handle files > 2GB, unless there is a limitation in TFileStream's implementation in Delphi 6. I'll have to check when I have some time

Comment: Hi, I am using 9.0 version of Indy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using Indy 9, which is a very old version of Indy that is no longer supported by the Indy team. That version of Indy indeed had a 2GB limitation on file transfers.

Although Delphi 6 was the version that introduced 64-bit streams, Indy 9 (specifically, the `WriteStream()` and `ReadStream()` methods of `TIdTCPConnection`, which `TIdFTP` uses for its transfers) never supported 64-bit streams.

If you need to handle file transfers > 2GB, you will have to upgrade to Indy 10 (or else forgo `TIdFTP` and implement the FTP protocol manually, then you can handle transfers however you want).

Indy 10 still supports back to Delphi 5.  Note that support for pre-Unicode compilers will be dropped in Indy 11.

**UPDATE**: as for your compiling error, it is because you are overriding methods which no longer exist in the base `TIdTCPConnection` class, they were moved to the `TIdIOHandler` class in Indy 10.  So you will need to update your code accordingly.  If you want to capture all of the commands and responses that `TIdFTP` sends/receives, you should override the virtual `SendCmd()` and `GetResponse()` methods, or else assign a `TIdConnectionIntercept`-derived object to `TIdFTP`'s `Intercept` property.

Comment: Thank you Remy for your ans. Please advise where I can get Indy 10 download link and instruction to install on Delphi 6. Most of the links for download is not working.

Comment: @Shazeb https://www.indyproject.org/2021/02/10/links-to-old-indy-website-pages-are-currently-broken/

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.

Comment: Hi Remy, Step by step I went though to link you have provided but it does not contain Indy 10.  am I missing ans steps or link? https://web.archive.org/web/20181113081026/http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.en.aspx   then https://web.archive.org/web/20181013112317/http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.EN.aspx then https://web.archive.org/web/20180628010731/http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/

Comment: Looks like you missed this part of the first link I gave you: "*Indy 10’s source code is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/*"

Comment: Thanks for your replay,  I went through the link you have provided. I am new to Indy Component. I am not able to find right version for Delphi 6 on GitHuB Repo, Can you please point me to right directory.

Comment: @Shazeb the install instructions are in the [1st link you quoted](https://web.archive.org/web/20181113081026/http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.en.aspx). There is no folder for Delphi 6, but there are package files. Compile and install the 5 `...60` packages mentioned at the top of the instructions: "*For Example: Delphi/C++Builder 6 is version 6.0, so the Indy packages are: IndySystem60, IndyCore60, IndyProtocols60, dclIndyCore60, dclIndyProtocols60*". Download just the `/Lib` folder, the files are in the `/Lib/System`, `/Lib/Core` and `/Lib/Protocols` folders

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Remy,

I have upgraded Indy component to 10. I am getting some error like method readln and writeln not found. When I am compiling with indy 9 it is working but with indy 10 it does not. I can see these methods are available in idiohandler but I am not clear what definition is missing

Thanks,

Regards
Nisar

Comment: @Shazeb Indy 10 was a major rewrite over Indy 9. For instance, many methods previously in `TIdTCPConnection` were moved to `TIdIOHandler`, as you noted, and many were also renamed (ie, most `WriteXXX()` methods were changed to `Write(XXX)` overloads). On the other hand, why were you calling `ReadLn()`/`WriteLn()` manually even in Indy 9? You probably shouldn't have been, unless you were sending custom commands, but even then you should have been using `TIdTCPConnection.SendCmd()`, and that hasn't changed in Indy 10.

Comment: @Shazeb Without seeing your actual code, I can't tell you how to update it from Indy 9 to 10.  Please edit your question to include the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Hi Remy, Code looks like that 
--------------------------------------------
TbaseFTP = Class(idftp)
Private
Jonwrite : TFTPDataLogEvent;
Jonread : TFTPDataLogEvent;

Public 
Procedure WriteLn(Const POut : string = ''); Override;
Function ReadLn(PTerminate : string = LF; const Ptimeout : Integer = IdTimeoutDefault; PMaxllength : integer = -1):string

---------Implemention Part---------
Procedure TbaseFTP.writeLn(Const Pout : string = '');
Begin
         if assigned (JOnWrite) then  JonWrite(Pout);
        inherited;
End;
-----------------------

Comment: It just inheriting from IdFTP class, I have not written these code but seems like it is for customize messaging. if I am adding library path for indy 9 it is successfully compiling but as I removing it. it is giving error that method not found. Thanks

Comment: @Shazeb that should have been posted as an edit to your original question, like I asked for, not posted in comments. But yes, those methods don't exist in `TIdTCPConnection` anymore, they were moved to the `TIdIOHandler` class. What you can do instead is override the virtual `SendCmd()` and `GetResponse()` methods, or assign a `TIdConnectionIntercept`-derived object to the `Intercept` property.

Comment: I have added code in question section I have removed override from both procedure writeln and readln. after that I compile it and it is working. Is it the right steps I have taken. one thing which I dont understand is that either it is indy 9 or 10 in both case I am inheriting IdFTP but in 9 it compiling but on 10 it does not. where we are linking the method in  TIdtcpconnection or TIdIOhandler.

Comment: @Shazeb "*I have removed `override` ... and it is working. Is it the right steps*" - not if you want to capture all of the commands that `TIdFTP` sends. I've already explained how to accomplish that. "*either it is indy 9 or 10 in both case I am inheriting IdFTP but in 9 it compiling but on 10 it does not*" - I've already explained that. I won't repeat myself again. Go re-read my past comments.

Comment: Hi Remy, Can you please give one example of --SendCmd() and GetResponse() methods, or assign a TIdConnectionIntercept-derived object to the Intercept property-- for the compiling issue I am having. I am working first time with Indy Components

Comment: @Shazeb "*Can you please give one example of SendCmd() and GetResponse() methods*" - why not just look at their declarations for yourself, and then `override` them like any other `virtual` method? "*or assign a TIdConnectionIntercept-derived object to the Intercept property*" - what part of that was unclear? `TIdConnectionIntercept` is an available component in Indy, it has `OnSend` and `OnReceive` events. You can use it as-is, or else derive from it and `override` its virtual `Send()` and `Receive()` methods. Either way, assign an instance of it to `TIdFTP`'s public `Intercept` property.

Comment: Thanks Remy I will look into it. Just last question. After compiling the source code with new indy 10 component. I am still getting this error. ------FTP send file failed. Reason: no data to read.------- for above 2gb file. is there anything I missing on this

Comment: @Shazeb I would have to see the code you are using to send a file. The *only* condition that causes a "no data to read" error is when `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` is called (by `TIdFTP.Put()` or `TIdFTP.StoreUnique()`) and `TStream.Read()` returns <= 0 indicating a failed read before the expected end-of-stream is reached.